# Why i can not use express node js on my server?

Tags: node.js

node js version `node -v` ===> `v6.3.1` was install on my server.

then i will install express by this step

```
npm init
```

in entry point: (index.js)

```
npm install express --save
```

then create app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

and then `node app.js`

and it's show error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1252:14)
    at listen (net.js:1288:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1384:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/app.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

how can i do ?

Comment: You can check what app is using the port with this command `$ lsof -i :3000` maybe you didn't close your app properly and it is still running in the background

Answer (score 1):

Choose a different port number as `3000` since some service is already bound to that port given that error.

Change it in the following line:

`app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))`

Answer (score 1):

`EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use.

So in this case, there must be running a service listening on port 3000 already.

Answer (score 0):

***you can run this command before start your app***

```
sudo pkill -kill node // to kill any node app running then start your app
```